# Unable to reset settings after running command that triggers bash script

Tags: autocmd

I have the following autocommand in my vimrc for vimwiki:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.md silent! VimwikiAll2HTML
```

The `VimwikiAll2HTML` triggers a custom script with `:! scriptname` to process all the files in the wiki.

It works, but there is the annoyance of the `"Press ENTER or type command to continue"` message that I want to suppress.

I tried this:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.md set shortmess=a | set cmdheight=2 | silent! VimwikiAll2HTML | set shortmess=filnxtToOF | set cmdheight = 1
```

But the last two commands to reset the `shortmess` and `cmdheight` properties just get ignored. What's the proper way to suppress the "Press Enter" command?  I also tried throwing a `<cr>` in there but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this answer worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2803985/1641112

For my particular problem, final solution is:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.md execute ':silent! VimwikiAll2HTML' | execute ':redraw!'
```

Comment: You don't really need the `:`s and the second command doesn't need `execute` (the first one needs it to allow `|` as a command separator.) This should work: `autocmd BufWritePost *.md execute 'silent! VimwikiAll2HTML' | redraw!`